# Lock tab changing on android with TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tabs

This has been often asked for TabHost, but in my case I'm using a TabLayout and did not found any similiar question or solution.

```
main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selectedTabTitleColor"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/unselectedTabTitleColor" />


    <com.sero583.app.view.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using as you may can see a custom View Pager and I managed to lock swiping but have no clue how to lock pressing at the Tab header, all methods which are available only return void's and I don't know how to dynamically set it back since I didn't found any method which is something like setViewingTab(int index);